ExecuteNonQuery throwing an exception "SQL database execute query failed. SQL Server may not be running"
I am trying execute a SQL Script file by calling
ExecuteNonQuery(somefile.sql) 

and I get an exception

SQL database execute query failed. SQL server may not be running

Please help.
I have a method that executes some .sql files in C#. When executing the first file, it does work fine. But when it tries to execute the next file (please see the else condition in the ExecuteFileBasedOnSequence method), it throws the exception. I tried executing the SQL Script on SQL Server and it works just fine.
EDIT:
This is the inner exception:

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Go'

But the script working fine when running on SQL Server.
Here is the C# code:
private void ExecuteFileBasedOnSequence(string fileToExecute, bool executeSQLBySequence = true)
{
    m_DBConnection.BeginTransaction();

    if (executeSQLBySequence)
    {
        // Read each line of the file into a stringbuilder object to be executed individually (may throw, should just pitch out of this function)
        using (StreamReader srSQL = new StreamReader(fileToExecute))
        {
            // Read each line of the file into a stringbuilder object to be executed individually (may throw, should just pitch out of this function)
            string sqlLine;

            StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();

            while (!srSQL.EndOfStream)
            {
                sqlLine = srSQL.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlLine) == false)
                {
                    // We don't actually execute the "GO" lines but can use them to determine when to call the executenonquery function
                    if (string.Compare(sqlLine, "GO", true) == 0)
                    {
                        // Make sure we have something to execute
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlString.ToString()) == false)
                        {
                            m_DBConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlString.ToString());
                        }

                        sqlString.Clear();
                    }
                    // Add the next line to the stringbuilder object
                    else
                    {
                        sqlString.AppendLine(sqlLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (StreamReader srSQL = new StreamReader(fileToExecute))
        {
            if (m_DBConnection != null)
            {
                m_DBConnection.Open();
                m_DBConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(srSQL.ReadToEnd()); //THIS ONE FAILS.
            }
        }
    }

    m_DBConnection.CommitTransaction();
}

I am calling the functions as follows:
// This one works 
ExecuteFileBasedOnSequence(@"Database\UpdateTriggersToSQL2017.sql");

// This one is failing    
ExecuteFileBasedOnSequence(@"Database\UpgradePharmSpecScripts.sql", false); 

Here is the failing SQL file (UpgradePharmSpecScripts.sql):
Use PharmSpecDB
Go

--PC1725E-590

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 23 FROM [PharmSpecDB].[dbo].[tblActivityLogMaster] WHERE Lower(strActivityLog) Like 'user rights%' AND LOWER(strActivityLogDesc) Like 'user rights%')
Begin
ALTER TABLE [PharmSpecDB].[dbo].[tblActivityLogMaster] DISABLE TRIGGER I_TRG_ACTIVITYLOGMASTER  
Insert into [PharmSpecDB].[dbo].[tblActivityLogMaster](strActivityLog,bDeleted,strActivityLogDesc) values ('User rights modified', 0, 'User rights modified')
ALTER TABLE [PharmSpecDB].[dbo].[tblActivityLogMaster] ENABLE TRIGGER I_TRG_ACTIVITYLOGMASTER
End

Edit: as suggested I removed the Go after the Use PharmSpec line in the script and I get a new error:

ExecuteNonQuery: Command text property has not been initalized


Probably you should post the whole exception, including all inner exceptions?

Sure let me do that

Make sure you are not disposing of connection in the method

Remove the "GO" from your script file and try again. To my knowledge, "GO" is only usable  and understood by Management Studio.

It's understood by other applications as well, @UweKeim, such as sqlcmd, Azure Data Studio, etc, however, it should not be used when calling SQL from a C# application. GO is not a T-SQL keyword, and the SQL Server libraries, for C#, don't recognise GO as a batch separator utility statement.

Thank you I removed the Go and it gives a new error saying "ExecuteNonQuery": Command text property has not been initalized."

Sounds like you lack a basic tutorial on how to use the SqlClient classes. How about checking that first and see whether this fixes your issues?

Sure lemme check...

Modified the script, added Go after UsePharmSpec and after the End. Changed the C# code removing the else block completely and it works.


Incorrect syntax near 'Go'."

Say it again with me for those in back:
GO is not part of the SQL language
It's a feature of certain tools used for separating multiple batches within a file, but it's not actually part of SQL itself. You can't send it to SQL Server other other databases directly and expect them to understand it.
It seems you already understand this, since the code is looking for that text in the input. But clearly the existing search is not sufficient. You may still have extra whitespace on the line, for example.
At very least you should be trimming the input before making the check (I suspect the issue is the Go in the UpgradePharmSpecScripts.sql has an extra space at the end). But also, be aware the reason why GO may appear in a file is because certain statements are not able to co-exist together. You may find a transaction is not always appropriate, and sometimes these batches MUST come on separate connections.

Another issue I see in that code is the IsNullOrEmpty() check in the loop.
It may be possible to have significant blank lines.
For example, you might have a multiline string literal, where the whitespace is important, and now you are skipping that text.
To give an example, since this looks like a process to update a pharmacy-related database across release versions, imagine you are providing data with each release on certain drugs, and that data is expanded to include default dosing instructions, where some instructions eventually grow to cover multiple paragraphs. This process will now destroy the paragraph separators.
This is important, because this will also impact your batch separator test!
If you ever have an SQL statement with a multiline string literal, where the one of the lines is "GO", this isn't smart enough to handle that.

Ultimately, if it were me, for this kind of process I would require each batch to have it's own file. The alternative, if you want something that will always work, is building a full SQL parser. Otherwise you'll always be playing whack-a-mole.
One final option is pushing the files through the sqlcmd utility, instead of running them through C# first. Your C# updater program might still orchestrate this process, but now the sqlcmd utility can handle the batch issues. Of course, it means running your update from a station with sqlcmd available, which isn't the case in Windows by default.
